# Actionmailer Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have added a contact form to my site and am having a problem, when the message is sent I get my flash message, "successfully sent", however the email never arrives in my inbox. I am in development mode at the moment and my app/config file looks like this

```
   class Application < Rails::Application

   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
   ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
   ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port    => 587,
    :domain  => "gmail.com",
    :user_name  => "myemail@gmail.com",
    :password   => "example",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }

     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
     :host => "gmail.com"
      }
```

My contact Controller is like this

```
      def new
       @message = Message.new
      end

     def create
     @message = Message.new(params[:message])
      if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
     else
     flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
     render :new
     end
    end 

     end
```

and finally my Notification Mailer

```
      class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default :from => "myemail@gmail.com"
      default :to => "myemail@gmail.com"

     def new_message(message)
     @message = message
     if message.file
      attachment_name = message.file.original_filename
      attachments[attachment_name] = message.file.read
     end
     mail(:subject => "[myemail@gmail.com] #{message.subject}")
    end
     end
```

Am I missing anything obvious here as I have implemented this in another site which worked fine, just cant figure out what is going on

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you analysed log? Search for something like `Sent mail to [RECEIVER'S EMAIL]` to check if mails was sent successfully. If you find similar log then check if your spam folder contains the mail?

Comment: I know this is an old question and you've likely moved on, but I'd first verify that you can successfully send the email using the console. Instantiate and deliver the email there.

Answer (score 1):

I know you set it in your app/config.rb, but I would ensure `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` isn't being overridden in your config/environments/development.rb

Comment: thanks for your answer, theres nothing in my config/environments/development that would override, still not working